# Getting Android HttpResponse message without the response code

Tags: android

I'm getting the response like this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
response.getStatusLine().toString());
```

In this case the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 invalid user credentials
```

Ho do I get the message only, without the code?

```
**invalid user credentials**
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

String messageOnly = statusLine.getReasonPhrase();
int codeOnly = statusLine.getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, do this

```
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

This will work!

Comment: simple one line peace of answer

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get  the message like this

```
         String message = response.getStatusLine().toString().substring(12);
```

Comment: The response will not always be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpURLConnection`'s `getResponseMessage()` See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
```

and then convert this input stream into string......

Answer (score 0):

Use getReasonPhrase() method of StatusLine interface.
e.g.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
 statusLine.getReasonPhrase()
```